# C# - Verify Google Cloud Platform token

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, token, verify

I'm asking for help to verify the GCP token (***x-gcp-marketplace-token***).

Basically I would like to implement a token verification explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/docs/partners/integrated-saas/frontend-integration?authuser=1#verify-jwt).

Expected language **C#**. preferable to be compatible with *.Net Core*.

***UPDATE***

This is what I have so far. It is a POC don't worry about fields naming.

Actually validation fails.

```
private async Task<OrderViewModel> GoogleResolveOrder(string token)
    {
        OrderViewModel result = new OrderViewModel { Transaction = new TransactionViewModel() };

        //Decode token
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        JwtSecurityToken tokenInfo = handler.ReadJwtToken(token);

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenInfo.Header.Kid) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenInfo.Payload.Sub) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenInfo.Payload.Iss))
        {
            string keyId = tokenInfo.Header.Kid;
            string keysEndpoint = tokenInfo.Payload.Iss;
            string procurementId = tokenInfo.Payload.Sub;

            //load gcp certificate
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(keysEndpoint);
            string googleCretificateInfoResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Dictionary<string, string> certifateInfo = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(googleCretificateInfoResponse);

            //Get public key from certificate
            string certificatePublicKeyText = certifateInfo[keyId];
            byte[] certicateStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(certificatePublicKeyText);
            X509Certificate certificate = new X509Certificate(certicateStream);

            try
            {
                // Verify token with public key, leave private key as null
                SecurityToken tokenValidated = null;
                TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {                                
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = tokenInfo.Payload.Aud[0],
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/cloud-commerce-partner@system.gserviceaccount.com",
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(certificate.GetPublicKey())
                };

                ClaimsPrincipal clainsResult = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out tokenValidated);

                //TODO- IF not exception Token is valid
                result.Transaction.MinimunQuantity = 1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result.Transaction.MinimunQuantity = -1;
                result.Transaction.FulfillmentStatus = ex.Message;
            }
            

            //TODO- Delete
            result.Transaction.OrgId = tokenInfo.Payload.Sub;
            result.Transaction.PlanName = tokenInfo.Payload.Iss;
            result.Transaction.PlanID = tokenInfo.Header.Kid;
            result.Transaction.Customer = String.Join(',', tokenInfo.Payload.Aud);
            result.Transaction.CustomerEmailId = tokenInfo.Payload.Exp.Value.ToString();
            result.Transaction.SubscriptionId = token;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I'm still working on this.

**Getting this error**:
IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: kid: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. Exceptions caught: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. token: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to write code for you? Show code you wrote once you have a problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, looking for some guidance or documentation regarding How to do it. I couldn't find any yet. As soon as make any progress I will share.

Comment: Google search for `c# JWT validation`. There are numerous examples on the Internet. Almost all JWT libraries include examples covering your question.

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks. I'll take a look. I've found something following your suggestions that might help me.

Comment: 1) If you are looking for someone to help with your code, read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 2) Validating a JWT is very simple. Your code is so complex, I have trouble understanding what you are trying to accomplish without a lot more details on endpoints, parameters, etc.

Comment: 3) A JWT is three objects concatenated together. The first two are strings, base64 encoded. The third is a binary signature of the other two, based64 encoded. The first two objects can be verified without requiring a library. The signature does require crypto libraries to help with the math.

Comment: After sometime I've found the solution to this. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to post a solution. In the next days once validation of my solution is complete I will post the solution as part of my question.